# What additional benefit does a phrase list give when used alongside a list entity

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I worked through this microsoft "Pizza" tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/tutorial-machine-learned-entity

Can anyone help me understand why the "Size" sub-entity benefits from having a Phrase List as well as a List Entity ?

The two features in question are:

1. SizePhraseList
   [A phrase list which just contains "small", "medium","large"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8LFT.png)
2. SizeListEntity
   [A list entity with phrases such as "small", "medium" etc WITH synonyms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd59j.png)

Would the model not work perfectly well with just the list entity ? What additional/complimentary benefit does the phrase list bring ?

[Here is the relevant section within the Microsoft Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/tutorial-machine-learned-entity#improve-size-extraction-with-phrase-list) it says "Improve size extraction with phrase list", but I don't understand why the model wouldn't just work fine with just the list entity.

I'd love to know, as I'm trying to set up my own language model, and want to use best practice.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: the Size ML subentity benefits from SizeListEntity as it normalizes the output value for Size entity so whenver the utterance inludes any of the words in the medium list "Medium" will be the extracted value. if you add SizeLIst as feature there wuld be no need to add a phraselist.

Answer (score 0):

Maher Refaat is correct with the comment.
To also point out, the Phrase list synonym will be the extracted entity, but the Normalized word will be separated elsewhere... I'd like this to change and both passed as the entity with Normalized and Synonym values being beside eachother. K.